# Why layout stretches because background

Tags: android, android-layout, background

i have layout size 1, when i set background i get size 2, how i can make that the layer is not stretched?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/items_pad_left"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/items_pad_right"
android:background="@drawable/item_background">
```

[image]

Comment: @bw as per the code, the height depends on the parent :-/

Comment: Try make background height as per you requirement or given static height to RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Because your are using: `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Use `wrap_content` instead or an arbitrary size like `100dp`

Comment: I do not can set height size

Comment: Why you cannot do that? wasn't wrap_content useful?

Comment: My item has a TextView, if text will be much, part of text is hide

Comment: If you use wrap_content, TextView will show full text even if text is long.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting a fixed width and height. Like -

> android:layout_width="200dp"
>   android:layout_height="100dp"

Comment: I do not can set height size